# Laravel Permission Spatie Package Use

Tags: php

Laravel Permission Spatie Package Use  Problem help me

[image: Error]

Comment: did you run migration command before using seeder? **php artisan migrate**

Comment: please provide error as text instead of image

Answer (score 0):

I can't really help a lot without code, but this issue seems similar to [Unable to resolve dependency - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62654902/unable-to-resolve-dependency-laravel)

You are probably not putting your class property in the constructor of your class.

> The reason is because the job is not invoked immediately. It is first constructed and then put in the queue where it will (at some point) be removed and "handled". Therefore handle does not have direct access to whatever parameter you pass in dispatch. The docs do show that handle can take parameters but those are only parameters that can be injected using dependency injection.

from [Unable to resolve dependency - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62654902/unable-to-resolve-dependency-laravel)